# HSVToColor in Android works kinda strange

Tags: java, android

Here's my code that is supposed to take a color int, convert it to HSV, add 0.5 to hue and convert back to int. But in the output, instead of 0xFF00FFFF gives -64768 ... any ideas what might be the problem?

```
    int c = 0xFFFF0000;   /// RED
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV( c, hsv ); /// splitting "c" into hsv
    hsv[0] = hsv[0]+0.5f;  /// adding 0.5 to Hue
    int c1 = Color.HSVToColor( hsv ); /// converting hsv back to int 
    Log.e("color: ", String.valueOf(c1) ); /// outputting new color int
    // should be "0xFF00FFFF" (light bule) , but is  "-64768" hmm...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing the string in hex.
Instead the raw int value is printed.

That value in hex is FFFF0300, which makes sense.

Comment: You're right! :) Any ideas now how to turn it into a hex int?

Comment: Use `Integer.toHexString(c1)`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to print a color in a hex string format, with a fixed size (2 character for color component).

```
public abstract class ColorHelper {

    public static String toARGBString(int color) {
        String ret;

        ret = "#";
        ret += fix(Integer.toHexString(Color.alpha(color)));
        ret += fix(Integer.toHexString(Color.red(color)));
        ret += fix(Integer.toHexString(Color.green(color)));
        ret += fix(Integer.toHexString(Color.blue(color)));

        return ret.toUpperCase();
    }

    private static String fix(String input) {
        if (input.length() == 1) {
            return "0" + input;
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: The same can be achieved with some `Formatter` magic: `String.format("#%08x", color);` (or `X` for uppercase) probably much faster (no `String +=` and less method calls)